# Python boto3 upload file to S3 from ec2

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

If I want to upload a file from my "mac" to S3, I can use

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name="us-west-1")
s3.meta.client.upload_file('/User/gantao/amz.jpg', 'gantao_created', 'amz.jpg')
```

But,

Is there any way to upload a file to S3 from EC2 instance (do not use SSH to EC2) ?

Comment: when you say **do not use SSH to EC2** can you detail out the scenario? If you do not want to SSH, you have to launch an EC2 machine from a custom AMI in which you have placed the python script which uploads to S3 and configured it run via cron job

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes."

The longer answer is that, in order to upload a file from an EC2 instance to S3, the deployed EC2 instance has to have the correct permissions to `put_object` to S3.

You can either do this by configuring your boto client inside your Python code, or by creating and assigning an IAM role with that permission to your EC2 instance.

The more secure way is to assign the IAM role, since it doesn't require you to have credentials in code or in a file in source control.

1. Use the AWS console to create an IAM role with permission to 'put' objects to the S3 bucket in question.
2. Assign the IAM role to your EC2 instance.

To create an IAM role:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

To add an IAM role to your EC2 instance:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easily-replace-or-attach-an-iam-role-to-an-existing-ec2-instance-by-using-the-ec2-console/